# Finding the element on a webpage through Python web-scraping issue

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I have trouble web-scraping with the code below. Through the "SP" element find, I'm able to print the numbers as shown on the webpage onto the excel spreadsheet with no issue, but when I try and apply the same thing for the "bets" element find, it would only print dashes no matter what element I put in the code, even with the specified webpage column element of "selection-result__table-column odds". What am I doing wrong?

Note: "bets" is the given bets just after the "SP" shown on the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook

# URL of the webpage
url = "https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/kempsey-20230828/all-races"

# Define a user agent
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"

# Set headers including the user agent in the request
headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent}

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL with headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # Find all elements with the class "selection-result"
    selection_result_elements = soup.find_all(class_="selection-result")
    
    # Create a new Excel workbook and select the active sheet
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    
    # Write the headers for the columns
    headers = ["Placing", "Trainer", "Jockey", "Horse", "SP", "Bets"]
    for col_index, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_index, value=header)
    
    # Write the extracted data into the Excel sheet
    for row_index, element in enumerate(selection_result_elements, start=2):
        placing = element.find(class_="selection-result__competitor-place").get_text(strip=True)
        trainer = element.find(class_="selection-result__info-trainer disable-pointer-events").get_text(strip=True)
        jockey = element.find(class_="selection-result__info-jockey disable-pointer-events").get_text(strip=True)
        horse = element.find(class_="disable-pointer-events").get_text(strip=True)
        
        SP = element.find(class_="selection-result__table odds").find_all(class_="selection-result__table-column")[1].find(class_="selection-result__table-column-details").get_text(strip=True)
        bets = element.find(class_="selection-result__table odds").find_all(class_="selection-result__table-column odds")[1].find(class_="selection-result__table-column-details").get_text(strip=True)
        
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=1, value=placing)
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=2, value=trainer)
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=3, value=jockey)
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=4, value=horse)
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=5, value=SP)
        sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=6, value=bets)
    
    # Save the workbook to a file
    wb.save("extracted_data.xlsx")
    print("Data saved to extracted_data.xlsx")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: The web page may be modified by JavaScript. If so, you need something like Selenium.